# How to get UFW to read current iptables rules after modification? (Ubuntu)

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, iptables, ufw, iptables-persistent

I am adding a chain using iptables:

```
iptables -N ETDROP
```

When I reboot, this is lost.
I read of many ways to make iptables rules permanent... however

You must remember, I am using UFW and UFW has this job of remembering your rules.

So the question is, how do I get UFW to realize that a new rule has just been added directly by iptables?

I tried `ufw reload` but no cookie.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/198398/ubuntu-how-to-add-an-iptables-rule-that-ufw-cant-create

Comment: I disagree.... If there is no way for UFW to import iptables then the accepted answer should be "This is impossible. you must use other methods."

Comment: Can ufw actually READ iptables or does it only WRITE?

Comment: The question is wrong.  ufw does not have the job of remembering your (iptables) rules; it has the job of remembering the iptables rules _which it added_.  ufw is to simplify iptables management for people with simple requirements; not a global replacement for the `iptables` command line.

Comment: excellent.. so you allege that ufw can only WRITE into iptables... never read them

Comment: No, I'm not alleging that.  For example, issue `ufw show raw` for a dump of the netfilter tables.  Read the [`ufw` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ufw.8.html)

Comment: That is just informational. ufw cannot act on that. its just a report and actually has nothing to do with the rules which ufw is managing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on various member's input, it seems that the answer is that:

**UFW can not IMPORT iptables rules**, it can only write them.

> UFW command->UFW->iptables and never the other way round.

So if you use UFW and want to add some complicated rule, you are stuffed!
e.g. adding a zone.

*Work arounds*

1. Use only iptables with iptables-persistent to reload its configuration on reboot.
2. Hybrid solution by editing ufw init files:
   Add your custom iptable 'compatible' rules in:

   /etc/ufw/before.rules or /etc/ufw/after.rules or /etc/ufw/user.rules

   These will be read by UFW after you restart it.
3. Hybrid solution by editing startup files e.g. rc.local
   Add your iptables command in a startup script and it will be available after reboot!

Answer (score 0):

iptables are not persistent by default. You need to save them and re-load on startup.   There is a package to do that automatically for that on most distrebutions.

On Ubuntu, Debian, Mint try:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

Comment: I know that, but it should not be necessary as UFW does exactly that